# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' [python openpyxl]

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to read some columns in a excel workbook with openpyxl, but i get that error with an if sentence. so what i want is build a F(x,y) graphic with the excel data but only with the specific values and i am trying to find those values with a for cicle.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

wb = load_workbook("intentito.xlsx")
she=wb.active
tt=list()
dd=list()
x=5500


for col in she.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_row=20,max_col=1,min_col=1, values_only=True):
    if col > 293 and col < 3475:
        tt.append((she.cell(row=A, column=col).value))
        dd.append((she.cell(row=B, column=col).value))
print(tt,dd)
```

this is an example

```
| A  | B   |
| ---| ----| 
|297 |59023|
|293 |   12|
|3478|   98|
```

so in this example my answer should be 297 appended to tt list and 59023 appended to dd list both integers

i read some answers but i am not a programer so it takes me too much time to undersatand the programing lenguage and abreviations. I relly apreciate an answer in spanish but any answer would be usefull.

thx,

Comment: Hello, there's a [version of SO in spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: it seems like `col `  is actually a tuple, so `she.iter_cols` must be a list of tuples , you probably want to compere only one of the values inside the tuple